# JTextArea not setting, throwing up error

Tags: java, get, set, jtextfield, jtextarea

so I'm pulling information from a database and placing them into fields/boxes in my GUI.

houseText and addressText are both textfields and they are setting fine, but oInfo is a JTextArea and it is causing an error when I try to set it. I also tried using 'append' but it didn't change anything. Any solutions?

```
infoHolder = dBStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM House");
infoHolder.next();

hName = infoHolder.getString("Name");
hAddress = infoHolder.getString("Address");
numRooms = infoHolder.getInt("numRooms");
Type = infoHolder.getString("Type");
charge = infoHolder.getString("roomCharge");
Access = infoHolder.getString("dAccess");
Info = infoHolder.getString("oInfo");

// the below print prints all the details to prove that the database has been read correctly.
System.out.println(hName + " " + hAddress + " " + numRooms + " " + Type + " " + charge + " " + Access + " " + Info);

houseText.setText(" " + hName); 
addressText.setText(" " + hAddress);
//roomNumber.setSelectedItem(numRooms);
//roomType.setSelectedItem(" " + Type);
//chargeRoom.setSelectedItem(" " + charge);
//access.setSelectedItem(" " + Access);
oInfo.setText(Info);
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at FinalBAndB.initialiseDatabase(FinalBAndB.java:124) 
    at FinalBAndB$1.run(FinalBAndB.java:274) 
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What error you are getting and from where are you calling this code? Is it an event handler, some other thread?

Comment: @npinti I am calling the code from my public static void main. The code above is inside it's own method called initialiseDatabase(); the textfields set perfectly, but the textarea (oinfo) is the issue. I have an exception handler on the method that prints the stack trace, but it isn't any more enlightening. infoHolder is a resultset.

Comment: What not enlightens Joe might enlighten Jack. A stack trace isn't FYEO.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at FinalBAndB.initialiseDatabase(FinalBAndB.java:124)
 at FinalBAndB$1.run(FinalBAndB.java:274)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

That's the stacktrace.

Comment: According to your stack trace, you have a `NullPointer` at `FinalBAndB.java:274`. From the information you have provided, it might be that the textbox you are using has not been initialized. Also, text components need to be modified through the Event Dispatcher thread to avoid issues.

Comment: @npinti , you are a hero. It was initialised, but incorrectly.

JTextArea oInfo = new JTextArea(); when replaced by

oInfo = new JTextArea(); worked perfectly (as I had already created an instance in the constructor. Thank you.

Comment: I have provided an answer below which also adds some additional information with regards to the EDT. Please make sure you are familiar with since it can help saving some problems down the line. If there is anything else which you think I should add to make it more clear, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer for completeness sake and some other minor information.

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at FinalBAndB.initialiseDatabase(FinalBAndB.java:124) 
    at FinalBAndB$1.run(FinalBAndB.java:274) 
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Implies that you are trying to access a non initialized object. As it turned out this was the case.

Additional information:
Like many other languages, Java uses a particular thread to perform all of its UI operation. In Java, this is called the `Event Dispatcher Thread` ([EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)). Since you are updating the text of a UI component, you need to ensure that the operation takes place through the EDT's operating context. To do this, one usually reverts to using the [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-). Please make sure that you are following this pattern to avoid any potential issues with cross thread operations.